# Why is this .htaccess directive not working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I want to redirect all missing images from some folders to a default image

```
#/versioned/track/server/tileserver/default.png [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ /versioned/track/server/tileserver/default.png [L]
```

It is located in **/var/www/versioned/track/server/tileserver**

I'm using ubuntu.

I've executed:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

All seems to be ok, but I get a 404 when accessing

```
http://localhost/versioned/track/server/tileserver/1.jpg
```

Comment: Is it displaying the default image? Or not working at all? If it's just the 404 you're worrying about you might just need to make the modifier `[R=302,L]`

Comment: It's not displaying the image at all

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the vhost definition as well? You can enable / disable the options one can modify via htaccess file.

The vhost option is `AllowOverride` that is decribed here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride.

Comment: File /etc/apache2/sites-available/default didn't exists, I've created it with
`<Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
                # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
                #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
        </Directory>`

Comment: If the default file was missing (what is strange for its own), the config is taken from the _/etc/apache2/apache2.conf_.
Just adding this file may not help, as long as it is not referenced in the main configuration.

Comment: Ok, now my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is like this, still the same issue
`<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: Hmm, strange. Can you please add some random date in your .htaccess file and check, if you get an error (http/500 or an entry in you error log)? Just to check, if the htaccess file is at least read by the server?